# How to send enum property in a json to .net core 3.1 API?

Tags: json, api, asp.net-core-3.1, dto

Everything looks good but I don't understand why I still get an error like:

```
 "System.InvalidCastException: The field of type DotnetCoreWebAPI.Enum+Blood must be a string, array or ICollection type."
```

I've left some meaningful snippets of code and the error I'm getting, below.

Model:

```
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(2)]
        public Enum.Blood Blood { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Cellphone { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Adress { get; set; }

    }
```

Enum:

```
    public class Enum
    {
        public enum Blood
        {
            ARhDpositive,
            ARhDnegative,
            BRhDpositive,
            BRhDnegative,
            ORhDpositive,
            ORhDnegative,
            ABRhDpositive,
            ABRhDnegative
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<UserReadDto> CreateUser(User userCreateDto)
        {
            var userModel = _mapper.Map<User>(userCreateDto);
            _repository.CreateUser(userModel);

            return Ok(userModel);
        }
```

Service Configurations:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer
            (Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));

            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
        opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));

            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

            services.AddScoped<IUserRepo, SqlUserRepo>();
        }
```

**Note:**
I use Postman when I test api

Answer (score 0):

I found out why problem occurs, I've wrote User instead of UserCreateDto in this line:

```
public ActionResult<UserReadDto> CreateUser(**UserCreateDto ** userCreateDto)
```